# How do I cook lamb tongues?

Tags: lamb, offal

They're cheap and delicious. (I had them at Fergus Henderson's restaurant in London.) But I have no idea what to do with them.  All I've read appears to say to treat them like beef tongue: slow simmering for a few hours until they can be peeled.

What do I do from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat them as you would corned beef. I like the pressure cooker method

Comment: The pressure cooker proved crucial.

Answer (score 1):

I would try simmering or braising until they are tender, which will make it easier to then skin them.  Stewing them slowly, like you mentioned works well especially if you're making a soup.